# How can I migrate my MiKTeX distro to another computer and keep my packages?

Tags: miktex, installing

I want to migrate my home distro of MiKTeX to my work desktop and keep all of my installed packages. I want to do this because my workplace blocks my attempts at downloading packages I've included in my documents.. I've been using [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) to create my documents because of this, but that becomes an issue when I want to embed images into my document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just zipping your user directory and main installation folder? You can install a regular installation and overwrite with your zipped files, I'd say.

Comment: Your techniccenter has nothing to do with the packages you have installed. You are thinking about your TeX distribution (probably MikTeX as you are using Windows).

Comment: I thought that my packages were stored in my editor not my distro. Does that mean I can literally zip and move my distro to get all my packages?

Comment: There is a miktex portable which you can transport on a stick. You can also download the miktex packages e.g. with a browser and save them in a folder and use this as a "local repository" to install packages in a normal miktex on the workplace.